# How to run program using OpenMesh

Tags: openmesh

I have read through most of OpenMesh's documentation, and am lost in how to run a simple program using OpenMesh. I followed the tutorial for making a basic cube and building the project: http://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-6.2-Documentation/a00068.html but nowhere do they mention how to RUN the program. The tutorial says to put the file that makes the cube in a particular folder: http://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-6.2-Documentation/a00066.html and I did this. It clearly compiled the code when I built it with cmake and make. After that I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you used the `CMakeLists.txt` as given in the page you linked as-is, the linker should create a file `MyOwnProject` within the directory where you executed `cmake` and then `make`. That's your executable. To run your program, execute that file, either by double-clicking it within a file manager (Explorer, if you are on Windows) or by typing `./MyOwnProject` on a Linux command line.